# iconv: conversion from UTF-16BE

Tags: c, encoding, character-encoding, cross-platform, iconv

Do all popular iconv implementations support conversion from UTF-16BE (i.e. UTF-16 with big-endian byte order)? GNU iconv supports this encoding, but what about the other implementations in common use? Specifically, what do mingw and the *BSDs support?

Should I rather do this conversion myself?

Comment: I'd be surprised if other iconv implementations *didn't* support UTF-16BE, but I have no hard data to support that.

Comment: Like caf noted, there are no special requirements for iconv, in fact it's okay to not support any encodings at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a big deal for you, you have an easy way out.  Just write an autoconf test for UTF-16BE support, and then make the configuration script fail with an error message if it's not present.

Then you can take your time to sift through the standards, or, just forget about the whole issue.

Since libiconv is LGPL and supports UTF-16BE ([website](http://www.gnu.org/s/libiconv/)), you can always point users to that.  There are some projects that include libiconv rather than rely on platform implementations.

Comment: Shifting through the standards won't take long - POSIX doesn't mandate *any* encodings to be supported by iconv.  An implementation that simply does `iconv_t iconv_open() { errno = EINVAL; return -1; }` would be conforming.

Comment: I have decided to use my own conversion code (<100 lines!), but thanks for the answer anyway.